# Steam does not allocate CPU on first attempt to start games

Tags: steam, technical-issues, windows-7

I have an issue with running Steam games that I hope someone can help with. I am running Steam on an older gaming PC that I built with:

- Intel Core i7 6700
- 32 GB of RAM
- Windows 7 64 bit

The Steam client opens fine but when I try to start a game it **does not allocate any CPU (the game executable have 0 processor resources in Task Manager) the first time** I run it.

The process will allocate memory but no CPU and will sit there without actually starting the game. I then go into Task Manager and kill the process then restart the game and everything works fine.

This is only for the first game that I play after opening the Steam client.

Has anyone experienced something similar and found a workaround?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean with Allocate CPU? What game is having this issue? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: @Lemon By allocate cpu I mean that under task manager the game executable will have 0 processor resources. If I kill the game process from within task manager and restart it, the game will start normally. This happens with any game I play after a fresh start of the Steam client. It is a quick fix to kill it with task manager and I have not found any other workaround.

Comment: What are some of the games you tried that have this issue?

Comment: Then this is not the place for you: asking for details should not be something to consider rude or unhelpful. Most of us here are trying to help, but we can't read minds.

Comment: Considering that Windows 7 is over 13 years old now I would say the problem is with the operating system. You can [upgrade to Windows 10 for free still](https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/14/21065140/how-to-upgrade-microsoft-windows-7-10-free-os), fyi.

Comment: Test the following things: 
1. Is it *any* steam game or only a particular one or few? Esp: Test an older title. 
2. If you cancel starting within Steam and hit play again, does that solve the problem? 
3. Run (Powershell): `$proc = Get-Process <nameofgame>; Write-Output $proc;`. Check the `ProcessorAffinity` property.

Comment: (Note: obtain the name of the process from Task manager or Explorer)